# Migrating Atlassian Confluence to Kuberntes

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, confluence

I am in the process of migrating Atlassian Confluence from on-prem to Kubernetes. I found the official docker image for confluence and was able to spin up the application. I need to configure ssl and i already have the key and certificate. I tried to import the certificates and restarted the server.xml and it is not working. Has any worked on confluence migration from on-prem to kubernetes/docker and if any can provide a link/experience related to the same, it would be helpful.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible, the healthcheck might be tricky and the reason for that is there is no automated install as far as I'm aware when it becomes live, meaning there will always been a manual configuration stage.

You're best looking at some package manager examples for this, which for Kubernetes is Helm. This allows you to iterate and rollback quickly.

Have a look at this [example](https://itnext.io/jira-on-kubernetes-by-helm-8a38357da4e)) which is for Jira, but the same flow should apply. Confluence and Jira are heavily related, so it should be relevant.